# How to delete refClass record in Doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine, many-to-many

I have many-to-many relations with the following tables.

post
tag
post_tag

I created three classes with Doctrine, so I have the following classes as well.

BasePost
BaseTag
BasePostTag

in the setUp() method, I defined relations. I like to delete tag record when I delete post record. So I simply put cascade as descirbed on Doctrine document.

```
$this->hasMany("Tag as Tags",array(
    'refClass' => 'PostTag',
    'local'=>'object_id',
    'foreign'=>'tag_id',
    'cascade'=> array('delete')
));
```

it works without a problem.

My questions is, how do I delete a record from post_tag table? 
Do I need to create a query myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to unlink : http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/ru/working-with-models#many-to-many-relations:deleting-a-link